# WP_Query paged returns 1 for all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm working on a site that uses the WPeCommerce plugin. The pagination has broken, it shows the first page products on all pages. At first the loop wasn't using a custom query so I added one with a paged parameter to see if it would help. But when I print the query, paged always returns 1, even if I hardcode it to a value like 2. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
<?php
    $prodArgs = array(
        'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
        'wpsc_product_category' => 'shoes',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
    );
    $prodArgs['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $prodQuery = new WP_Query($prodArgs);

    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = NULL;
    $wp_query   = $prodQuery;

    $count = 1;
?>
<div class="hidden">
    <pre>
        <?php print_r($prodQuery); ?>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: use `var_dump` to debug the value of `get_query_var`. PHP's type juggling and bool evaluation can be quite tricky some times.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

```
<?php
                    $wp_query = array(
                            'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
                            'wpsc_product_category' => $thd_category->slug,
                            'posts_per_page' => 12,
                            'paged' => get_query_var('page')
                        );

                    query_posts($wp_query);

                    $count = 1;
                ?>
                <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `paged` parameter in wp query.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$prodArgs = array(
                        'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
                        'wpsc_product_category' => 'shoes',
                        'posts_per_page' => 12,
                        'paged' => $paged
                    );

                    $prodQuery = new WP_Query($prodArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this too, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Dump `$paged` ?

Comment: It returns int(1) on every page.

Comment: I ment to dump `get_query_var('paged')`

Comment: I did. It's also returning int(1)